# I need help making calculations from entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I am very new to python and quite interested in learning it. Tried googling an answer for this but couldn't find one.

I'm doing a project for myself to get the price of the fuel costs (daily, monthly and yearly costs).

*Fuel consumption (liter/100km) / 100 * kilometers driven (per day) * fuel cost (per liter)*

I am trying to get the data from entry, then calculating it and then displaying the results in labels. It seemed like an easy beginner practice but ended up being a bit too difficult because I couldn't find on google something that I would understand.

Here's what I got to:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Consumption calculator")

root.geometry("300x300")

root.minsize(300, 500)
root.maxsize(300, 500)

#Label

label1 = Label(root, text = "Fuel consumption", pady=20,padx=60)
label1.grid(row=0)

label2 = Label(root, text = "Current fuel cost", pady=20,padx=60)
label2.grid(row=2)

label3 = Label(root, text = "Kilometers per day", pady=20,padx=60)
label3.grid(row=4)

akkuna4 = Label(root, text = " ", pady=10,padx=60)
akkuna4.grid(row=5)

#Entry

txt1 = Entry(root, width=5, state=NORMAL)
txt1.grid(row=1)

txt2 = Entry(root, width=5, state=NORMAL)
txt2.grid(row=3)

txt3 = Entry(root, width=5, state=NORMAL)
txt3.grid(row=5)

#Button

btn = Button(text="Calculate",
              font=("Arial",15,"bold"))
btn.grid(row=7)

#

root.mainloop()
```

I wanted to get the results to update in real-time whenever you typed in entry but I don't know if it's possible so I just resulted to using the button. Please let me know if it's possible to get them to calculate in real time without pressing a button! (It probably is)

I was trying out commands and "var-stuff" (I don't even know what that really does yet). I couldn't figure out how it would be possible.

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you really want, but what would be the point in calculating something with parts of numbers while you are entering them?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I just thought it would be nice. It’s not necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a variable that will be connected to your entries:
In the example, the code prints to the screen the values taken from the entry.

```
import tkinter as tk


def func(*args):
    # *args allows passing a variable number of non-keyword arguments to the 
    # function 
    label1.configure(text=var.get())


root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)  # var points to the entry1 input.
label1 = tk.Label(root)

entry1.pack()
var.trace('w', func)  # w for write, and trace for following var
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Now your job is to implement a similar algorithm in your code!
Good luck :)